# A puzzle of balance

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

**What's the seven-letter answer I'm looking for?**

[image]

Comment: Just wanted to say; Although the 'knowledge'-tag is there, it's very likely that someone will solve this puzzle without any (or very little) use of Google. It's pretty much common knowledge. So don't hang up on that tag.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The seven-letter answer is:

> [**YIN-YANG**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yin_and_yang)

Because what we have been provided with here is:

> a template and instructions for how to draw the yin-yang symbol from Chinese philosophy:
>
>  [image: Yin-yang symbol]

To follow these instructions:

> First, number the seven red dots from top to bottom as 1 to 7, and interpret 'Centre of c' as 'Centre of **circle**'.
>
>  Now, for each of the 5 lines of instructions, draw circles which pass through the two numbered points listed, with the circle's centre positioned exactly halfway between them (i.e. the two points fall at opposite ends of a diameter of the circle). Where a 'subtraction' instruction is listed to the right of the table, remove that section of the circle.

Let's do this, then:

> Circle 1-7:
>
>  [image: Circle 1-7]
>
>  Circle 1-4:
>
>  [image: Circle 1-4]
>
>  - left 1/2:
>
>  [image: Removing left half of Circle 1-4]
>
>  Circle 2-3:
>
>  [image: Circle 2-3]
>
>  Circle 4-7:
>
>  [image: Circle 4-7]
>
>  - right 1/2:
>
>  [image: Removing right half of Circle 4-7]
>
>  Circle 5-6:
>
>  [image: Circle 5-6]

Finally:

> Colour areas containing a 'W' **white**, and areas containing a 'B' **black**, and the symbol is complete!
>
>  [image: Yin-yang symbol (again)]

The title is relevant here because:

> Yin and yang are a Chinese philosophical concept describing interconnected opposing forces. The two halves of the symbol exist in perfect *balance*, with the two colours appearing as equal-sized interlocking shapes.

Comment: I really really thought a hint would be necessary. Nice to see it solved :) Well done!

Comment: @Prim3numbah Stiv is in your head. Great solve and nice write-up!